# Switch like context manager in Python

Tags: python, context-manager

This is self-explaining example with usage in doctests (it's not that fast as implementation with dict key-lookups, but it's a lot more readable, and don't require callables and lambdas):

```
class Switch(object):
    """
    Switch, simple implementation of switch statement for Python, eg:

    >>> def test_switch(val):
    ...   ret = []
    ...   with Switch(val) as case:
    ...     if case(1, fall_through=True):
    ...       ret.append(1)
    ...     if case(2):
    ...       ret.append(2)
    ...     if case.call(lambda v: 2 < v < 4):
    ...       ret.append(3)
    ...     if case.call(lambda v: 3 < v < 5, fall_through=True):
    ...       ret.append(4)
    ...     if case(5):
    ...       ret.append(5)
    ...     if case.default:
    ...       ret.append(6)
    ...   return ret
    ...
    >>> test_switch(1)
    [1, 2]

    >>> test_switch(2)
    [2]

    >>> test_switch(3)
    [3]

    >>> test_switch(4)
    [4, 5]

    >>> test_switch(5)
    [5]

    >>> test_switch(7)
    [6]


    >>> def test_switch_default_fall_through(val):
    ...   ret = []
    ...   with Switch(val, fall_through=True) as case:
    ...     if case(1):
    ...       ret.append(1)
    ...     if case(2):
    ...       ret.append(2)
    ...     if case.call(lambda v: 2 < v < 4):
    ...       ret.append(3)
    ...     if case.call(lambda v: 3 < v < 5, fall_through=False):
    ...       ret.append(4)
    ...     if case(5):
    ...       ret.append(5)
    ...     if case.default:
    ...       ret.append(6)
    ...   return ret
    ...
    >>> test_switch_default_fall_through(1)
    [1, 2, 3, 4]

    >>> test_switch_default_fall_through(2)
    [2, 3, 4]

    >>> test_switch_default_fall_through(3)
    [3, 4]

    >>> test_switch_default_fall_through(4)
    [4]

    >>> test_switch_default_fall_through(5)
    [5]

    >>> test_switch_default_fall_through(7)
    [6]
    """

    class StopExecution(Exception):
        pass

    def __init__(self, test_value, fall_through=False):
        self._value = test_value
        self._fall_through = None
        self._default_fall_through = fall_through
        self._use_default = True
        self._default_used = False

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        if exc_type is self.StopExecution:
            return True

        return False

    def __call__(self, expr, fall_through=None):
        return self.call(lambda v: v == expr, fall_through)

    def call(self, call, fall_through=None):
        if self._default_used:
            raise SyntaxError('Case after default is prohibited')

        if self._finished:
            raise self.StopExecution()
        elif call(self._value) or self._fall_through:
            self._use_default = False
            if fall_through is None:
                self._fall_through = self._default_fall_through
            else:
                self._fall_through = fall_through
            return True

        return False

    @property
    def default(self):
        if self._finished:
            raise self.StopExecution()

        self._default_used = True

        if self._use_default:
            return True

        return False

    @property
    def _finished(self):
        return self._use_default is False and self._fall_through is False


class CSwitch(Switch):
    """
    CSwitch is a shortcut to call Switch(test_value, fall_through=True)
    """
    def __init__(self, test_value):
        super(CSwitch, self).__init__(test_value, fall_through=True)
```

Comment: If you want to preserve the `case/break` syntax of C, here is an interesting implementation: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/410692/.

Answer (score 4):

I like your trick to create this syntactic sugar.  The implementation is also pretty good, as are the doctests.

#### Feature suggestions

I think it would be nice if a `case()` could test for multiple values.   A `case('jack', 'queen', 'king')` should match if the `Switch` was created with any of those three strings.

It would also be nice if there were a `case.match()` that performed a regular expression match.

#### Minor issues

1. If execution ends up inside `case.call()` due to fall-through, then I would expect the test function not to be called at all, as a kind of short-circuiting behaviour.  Specifically,

   ```
   elif call(self._value) or self._fall_through:
   ```

   should be reversed and written as

   ```
   elif self._fall_through or call(self._value):
   ```
2. Having a parameter named `call` when the method is also named `call` is confusing.  I suggest renaming the parameter to `test`.
3. Avoid testing variables for equality with `True` and `False` explicitly.  Just use boolean expressions.  For example, in `__exit__()`, change

   ```
   def __exit__(exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
       if exc_type is self.StopExecution:
           return True
       return False
   ```

   to

   ```
   def __exit__(exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
       return exc_type is self.StopExecution
   ```
4. Initialize `_fall_through` to `False` instead of `None`; it's slightly more informative.
5. Rename `expr` → `case_value`.  Rename `_value` → `_switch_value`.
6. Rename / invert `_use_default` to `not _matched_case`, because `_use_default` is too confusingly similar to `_default_used`.  Also, by inverting the logic, all three private variables can be initialized to `False`, which is more elegant.
7. Instead of a `_finished` property, write a `_check_finished()` method that raises `StopException` too.

#### Proposed solution

```
import re

class Switch(object):
    """
    Switch, simple implementation of switch statement for Python, eg:

    >>> def test_switch(val):
    ...   ret = []
    ...   with Switch(val) as case:
    ...     if case(1, fall_through=True):
    ...       ret.append(1)
    ...     if case.match('2|two'):
    ...       ret.append(2)
    ...     if case.call(lambda v: 2 < v < 4):
    ...       ret.append(3)
    ...     if case.call(lambda v: 3 < v < 5, fall_through=True):
    ...       ret.append(4)
    ...     if case(5, 10):
    ...       ret.append('5 or 10')
    ...     if case.default:
    ...       ret.append(6)
    ...   return ret
    ...
    >>> test_switch(1)
    [1, 2]

    >>> test_switch(2)
    [2]

    >>> test_switch(3)
    [3]

    >>> test_switch(4)
    [4, '5 or 10']

    >>> test_switch(5)
    ['5 or 10']

    >>> test_switch(10)
    ['5 or 10']

    >>> test_switch(7)
    [6]


    >>> def test_switch_default_fall_through(val):
    ...   ret = []
    ...   with Switch(val, fall_through=True) as case:
    ...     if case(1):
    ...       ret.append(1)
    ...     if case(2):
    ...       ret.append(2)
    ...     if case.call(lambda v: 2 < v < 4):
    ...       ret.append(3)
    ...     if case.call(lambda v: 3 < v < 5, fall_through=False):
    ...       ret.append(4)
    ...     if case(5):
    ...       ret.append(5)
    ...     if case.default:
    ...       ret.append(6)
    ...   return ret
    ...
    >>> test_switch_default_fall_through(1)
    [1, 2, 3, 4]

    >>> test_switch_default_fall_through(2)
    [2, 3, 4]

    >>> test_switch_default_fall_through(3)
    [3, 4]

    >>> test_switch_default_fall_through(4)
    [4]

    >>> test_switch_default_fall_through(5)
    [5]

    >>> test_switch_default_fall_through(7)
    [6]
    """

    class StopExecution(Exception):
        pass

    def __init__(self, switch_value, fall_through=False):
        self._switch_value = switch_value
        self._default_fall_through = fall_through
        self._fall_through = False
        self._matched_case = False
        self._default_used = False

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        return exc_type is self.StopExecution

    def __call__(self, case_value, *case_values, **kwargs):
        def test(switch_value):
            return any(switch_value == v for v in (case_value,) + case_values)
        return self.call(test, **kwargs)

    def call(self, test, fall_through=None):
        if self._default_used:
            raise SyntaxError('Case after default is prohibited')

        self._check_finished()
        if self._fall_through or test(self._switch_value):
            self._matched_case = True
            self._fall_through = fall_through if fall_through is not None else self._default_fall_through
            return True

        return False

    def match(self, regex, fall_through=None):
        if self._default_used:
            raise SyntaxError('Match after default is prohibited')

        self._check_finished()
        if isinstance(regex, str):
            regex = re.compile(regex)
        if self._fall_through or regex.match(str(self._switch_value)):
            self._matched_case = True
            self._fall_through = fall_through if fall_through is not None else self._default_fall_through
            return True

        return False

    @property
    def default(self):
        self._check_finished()
        self._default_used = True
        return not self._matched_case

    def _check_finished(self):
        if self._matched_case and not self._fall_through:
            raise self.StopExecution()


class CSwitch(Switch):
    """
    CSwitch is a shortcut to call Switch(switch_value, fall_through=True)
    """
    def __init__(self, switch_value):
        super(CSwitch, self).__init__(switch_value, fall_through=True)
```

Comment: Thanks, I've added also ability to have multiple regexp patterns within single `case/match` call, code is available on pypi: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/switch/1.1.0